# .NET Core 3.1 - console app + EF - .Include not loading data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, include

I usually find a way to make this work but here, **the included data are null, running in a C# console application**

(While **the same code works in my web application**)

both **Contact** and **Company** are **null**, *EF does not fetch associated data*

```
var context = new MyDBContext (configuration);
var leads = context.Leads.AsQueryable()
                            .Include(p => p.Company)  <<< does not create jointure
                            .Include(p => p.Contact)  <<< does not create jointure
                            .ToList();
```

I expect the associated Tables to be populated in my object

I tried disabling the lazy loading but apparently **LazyLoadingEnabled** is not part the configuration class

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    IConfiguration configuration;

    public MyDBContext (IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;  <<< cannot compile
    }
```

**I create my db context like I do it in my web app**

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBContext");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                                    {
                                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                                        maxRetryCount: 10,
                                        maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                        errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                    })
                                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                                    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    }

    ...
```

this is how I create the configuration

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
configuration = builder.Build();
```

thanks for your help on this

[edit]

here is the lead class:

```
[Table("leads")]
public class Lead
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pls show your Lead class.

Comment: If the data appears in the web app but not the console then I would be highly suspicious of the connection string the console application is resolving.  The other possibility might be dependent on the location of the DbContext, entities, and any configuration if using EntityTypeConfiguration and something like modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly where the web application is able to resolve the locations of the entity type configurations, but the console based one does not and defaults to convention where the FKs aren't wired up.

Comment: the connection string is fine, the base class (Lead) is having data, but not the FK tables

Comment: "but the console based one does not and defaults to convention where the FKs aren't wired up" how do I solve that ? I have the same issue in my web app when using entity outside of the Web controllers classes

Answer (score 1):

I think, for navigation properties to work EF core needs FKs. But not sure that how this is working thru  the  Web App. If possible please try with FKs like:
[Table("leads")]
public class Lead
{
[Required]
public int? Id { get; set; }

```
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: still the same, data is not loaded

Comment: at least I get the id's so I can fetch data manually but this s....